# How to stop bounds of zoomed image while scrolling?

Tags: ipad, ios, uiscrollview

```
 UIScrollView1.contentSize=CGSizeMake(UIImageView1.frame.size.width, UIImageView1.frame.size.height);
 UIScrollView1.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;
 UIScrollView1.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
 UIScrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
 UIScrollView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 UIScrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
 UIScrollView1.pagingEnabled=YES;

 UIScrollView1.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
 UIScrollView1.delegate = self;
 [UIScrollView1 addSubview:UIImageView1];
 [self.view addSubview:UIScrollView1];
```

This is my coding to use scrollview drag the zoomed image.While zooming time image move fast. Anybody hep to overcome this problem.

```
Thanks,
```

Senthilkumar

Comment: Can you elaborate on "While zooming time image move fast"?